# How to pass values from one redux-sagas generator to another

Tags: javascript, generator, redux-saga

I want the value from apiCall to be try catched in the storedApiCall function and then have that value passed to the loginHandle generator. So the problem is json equals undefined

```
function* storedApiCall(name,route,kwargs){
    try {
        const response = yield call(apiCall, route, kwargs);
    } catch(e) {
        console.log('exception: ' + e.message);
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

so I want the value of json to be the same as the value of response

```
function * loginHandle(action) {

     const json =  yield call(storedApiCall,'name', '/api/auth/login', {username, password});
     console.log('result is');
     console.log(json)
}
```

Comment: try calling call(storedApiCall, ....)

Comment: didnt seem to work
do i change anything else?

Comment: Not certain what expected result is? Why is a generator necessary?

Comment: response and json should equal the result of the apiCall function. I think its necessary to handle async in redux sagas

Comment: What issue are you having with JavaScript at Question?

Comment: I am getting the variable json equaling undefined instead of equaling response

Comment: Where is `call` defined?

Comment: its part of redux sagas https://redux-saga.js.org/docs/api/

Comment: Why do you think a `yield` expression would have a value? Perhaps try `const json = call(storedApiCall, blah blah); yield json`. Please do not take this as endorsement of the code.

Comment: if response has a value I would expect that json also has a value

Comment: it is some sort of async, ive worked with async stuff in generators and it worked perfectly, your code seems ok, what is the result of json?

Comment: the console.log prints undefined

Comment: Yes, your `storedApiCall` function returns `undefined`, since it does not return anything

Comment: I thought yield would return it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

managed to get it working by using channels

```
export default function * rootSaga() {
    chan = yield call(channel,buffers.expanding(10))
```

defined channel in the root saga and declared it at the top of the file

the passing function

```
yield put.resolve(chan,response);
```

the recieving function

```
yield call(passingFunction)
const response = yield take(chan)
```

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, what Vladislav lhost said is true, json returns undefined because storeApiCall returns nothing.

```
function* storedApiCall(name,route,kwargs){
    try {
        const response = yield call(apiCall, route, kwargs);
        return response;

    } catch(e) {
        return e.message;
        console.log('exception: ' + e.message);
        console.log(e);
    }
}
```

now it might have something on json.

Comment: I get a blank object on return

Comment: the yield should return it to the other function right?

Comment: yeah, it should have returned, a generator works almost the same as a norman function, except for a few differences, but has the same logic.